# flutter "could not generate 'fromJson' code for Type" error on Nullable

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I upgraded my project to Null-Safety but I'm getting an error when I define a property as null when running the build_runner:

```dart
@JsonKey()
late Guid? colonizedStellarObjectId;
```

The type Guid is from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_guid), but I modified it to support null-safety:

```dart
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart';

/// Class that emulates as closely as possible the C# Guid type.
class Guid {
  static const String _defaultGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

  /// The Guid whose value is the default sequence of characters that represent a 'zero-value' UUID in .Net "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  static Guid get defaultValue => new Guid(_defaultGuid);

  String? _value;

  /// Constructor, expects a valid UUID and will throw an exception if the value provided is invalid.
  Guid(String v) {
    _failIfNotValidGuid(v);
    _value = v;
  }

  /// Generates a new v4 UUID and returns a GUID instance with the new UUID.
  static Guid get newGuid {
    return new Guid(Uuid().v4());
  }

  /// Checks whether a value is a valid Guid
  /// Returns false if 'guid' is null or has an invalid value
  /// Returns true if guid is valid
  static bool isValid(Guid? guid) {
    if (guid == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return isUUID(guid.value);
    }
  }

  _failIfNotValidGuid(String? v) {
    if (v == null || v.isEmpty) {
      v = _defaultGuid;
    }
    final isInvalid = isUUID(v) == false;
    if (isInvalid) {
      throw new FlutterGuidError("Value '$v' is not a valid UUID");
    }
  }

  /// Gets the UUID value contained by the Guid object as a string.
  String get value {
    if (_value == null || _value!.isEmpty) {
      return _defaultGuid;
    } else {
      return _value!;
    }
  }

  /// Performs a case insensitive comparison on the UUIDs contained in two Guid objects.
  /// Comparison is by value and not by reference.
  bool operator ==(other) {
    return this.value.toLowerCase() == other.toString().toLowerCase();
  }

  /// Returns the hashCode.
  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return super.hashCode;
  }

  /// Gets the UUID value contained by the Guid object as a string.
  @override
  String toString() {
    return value;
  }
}

class FlutterGuidError extends Error {
  final String message;

  FlutterGuidError(this.message);
}
```

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `colonizedStellarObjectId`.
To support the type `Guid` you can:
* Use `JsonConverter`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html
* Use `JsonKey` fields `fromJson` and `toJson`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/fromJson.html
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/toJson.html
package:astrogame_app/models/stellar/base_types/colonizable_stellar_object.dart:14:14
   ╷
14 │   late Guid? colonizedStellarObjectId;
   │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

I have written a converter for the json serialization:

```dart
class GuidConverter implements JsonConverter<Guid, String> {
  const GuidConverter();

  @override
  Guid fromJson(String json) {
    return Guid(json);
  }

  @override
  String toJson(Guid object) {
    return object.toString();
  }
}
```

When I set the property as not-null, everything is fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experience of this problem not with json_serializable but with floor (which deals with serializing dart classes for storage in a sqlite database), but the mechanism I would say that it is the same. Your JsonConverter is able to serialize a Guid instance, but since the colonizedstellarobjectid field can be null, the toJson() method should also accept null.

Then your GuidConverter has to subclass `JsonConverter<Guid?, String>`.

However often, if a converter must even serialize the null value, is useful to use even as output a nullable type, so in your case the base class would be `JsonConverter<Guid?, String?>`.

Example:

```dart
class GuidConverter implements JsonConverter<Guid?, String?> {
  const GuidConverter();

  @override
  Guid? fromJson(String? json) {
    if (json==null) {
      return null;      
    }
    return Guid(json);
  }

  @override
  String? toJson(Guid? object) {
    if (object==null) {
      return null;
    }
    return object.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: But the toJson() method is automatically generated, if I edit it, the next run of build_runner will overwrite it

Comment: @Daniel DirtyNative Martin : Your comment is not clear to me (it puts the doubt that I have not really understood your problem), but I verified that JsonConverter must be able to manage null values. I hope the example clarifies what I meant

Comment: Anyway, is there a reason why you chose to serialize Guid through a special JsonConverter instead of annotate even the Guid class with @JsonSerializable? JsonConverter is designed when you are not accessing the source of the class, but in your case if I'm not mistaken you wrote this version of the Guid class, then you could annotate it. If you want to try this approach, keep in mind that the class that contains the "Guid? colonized.." field must be annotated with @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true), otherwise the correct code will not be created (the doc of explicitToJson explains why)

Comment: I use a converter because I want to deserialize the Guid from a String and not from a Map.

Comment: Okay I solved it. I already had written a Converter which accepts a Guid? but I only added it inside an abstract class, not inside the inherited one...

Comment: Right, if you need to serialize to String or int then the only solution is sublcass JsonConverter